# Javascript Rsjx: sorting chunks of data by date

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
[{"creationDate":"2011-03-13T00:17:25.000Z","fileName":"IMG_0001.JPG"},
{"creationDate":"2009-10-09T21:09:20.000Z","fileName":"IMG_0002.JPG"}]

[{"creationDate":"2012-10-08T21:29:49.800Z","fileName":"IMG_0004.JPG",
{"creationDate":"2010-08-08T18:52:11.900Z","fileName":"IMG_0003.JPG"}]
```

I use a HTTP get method to receive data.  Unfortunately, while I do receive this data in chunks, it is not sorted by creationDate DESCENDING.
I need to sort these objects by creationDate my expected result would be.

```
[{"creationDate":"2012-10-08T21:29:49.800Z","fileName":"IMG_0004.JPG"},
{"creationDate":"2011-03-13T00:17:25.000Z","fileName":"IMG_0001.JPG"}]

[{"creationDate":"2010-08-08T18:52:11.900Z","fileName":"IMG_0003.JPG"},
{"creationDate":"2009-10-09T21:09:20.000Z","fileName":"IMG_0002.JPG"}]
```

Here's what I tried:

```
dataInChunks.map(data => {
    return data.sort((a,b)=> {
      return new Date(b.creationDate).getTime() - new Date(a.creationDate).getTime();
    });
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

This works only but only 1 object at a time which results in giving me the very top result.  I need some way to join these chunks together and sort them and in some way break the whole object again into chunks of two.

Are there any RSJX operators I can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the call definitely completes (which it should) then you can just use [toArray](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/toarray.md) which as the name suggests returns an array, which you can then sort. The point of toArray is that it won't produce a stream of data but will wait until the observer completes and return all values:

```
var allData = dataInChunks.toArray().sort(/*sorting logic*/);
```

However, if you are required to show the data in the browser as it arrives (if the toArray() approach makes the UI feel unresponsive), then you will have to re-sort the increasing dataset as it arrives:

```
var allData =[];
dataInChunks
    .bufferWithCount(4)
    .subscribe(vals => {
        allData = allData.concat(vals);
        allData.sort(/* sort logic*/);
    })
```

This is slightly hacky as it's relying on a variable outside the stream, but yet get the idea. It uses a buffer [bufferWithCount](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/bufferwithcount.md) which will allow you to limit the number of re-sorts you do.

TBH, I would just go with the toArray approach, which begs the question why it's an observable in the first place! Good luck.